# /bin/sh: 1: :/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/bin/nvcc: not found

Tags: nvidia, cuda, bashrc

when i used `nvidia-smi` i got the version of `cuda` is `11.0` but I checked the path `/usr/local` and found `/cuda11.1`

i got an error when I installed mmcv package

```
/bin/sh: 1: :/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/bin/nvcc: not found
```

my bashrc is

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```